# showing form with prefilled values when back button is pressed in grails app

Tags: grails, gsp

I have develop a small app in grails, First page I give a zip code to search neary by stores and select it, press next button, on second page I enter the customer details and press the next button to display entered values on third page before saving it. Now If the user wants to edit the values he needs to go back to the same form by pressing back button/link, I am able to redirect to the second page using `<b><g:link action="register" controller="customer" params="${[customer:customer]}"/>Test </g:link></b>` but the form fields are coming empty, how do I fill those form fields with the value I had added. Can anyone please guide me how to go about ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Have you taken a look at [Grails web Flow](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html#webflow) documentation - it's exactly what you are looking for.

EDIT:

Basically you need to maintain state either on the server side (e.g. webflow or roll your own) or client side. For the client side - you probably need some ajax functionality - a quick search revealed the following jquery libs

- http://thecodemine.org/#
- http://luhman.org/blog/2011/08/25/jquery-wizard-controls
- http://www.manasinc.com/best-free-jquery-wizard-plugins/

In either case the difficult part is the "maintaining state", and on the server side it probably means using session variables, which can be difficult because you'll have to worry about issues like concurrency. Maybe other's can chime in on their experience with client-side form wizards, my experience is pretty limited.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I was thinking is it possible to do without using Webflow ? else I will go with the webflow.